# Minecraft Pocket edition on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, minecraft, porting

Does anyone know if Minecraft Pocket edition is on Ubuntu touch? Because I am thinking
 of installing it but don't want to lose all my worlds.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official website, [Minecraft Pocket Edition](https://minecraft.net/pocket) is only available on Android and iOS.  So you won't be able to run it under Ubuntu Touch at this point in time.